# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 8):

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Hi i have the javascript code inside XML. My code breaks if i write for loop .the function in javascipt.

```
{
<script language="javascript">
        IWEventRegistry.addFormHandler("onForminit",init);
        var NextPath="/iwmnt/default/main/sandbox/EDITION/";
        IWEventRegistry.addItemHandler("/Config/NextEditionVpathD","onItemChange",concatPath);
        IWEventRegistry.addItemHandler("/Config/PreviousEditionD","onItemChange",setPrev);
        function init()
        {
            alert("Hello");
            var server = window.location.hostname;
            var param=new Object();
            var callUrl1= "http://"+server+"/iw-cc/teamsite/genEditions.jsp?path1="+NextPath;
            IWDatacapture.callServer(callUrl1,param,true);
            alert("INIT End");

        }

            function genIds1(item)
            {
                var str=item.toString();
                alert(str);
                var n=str.split("-");
                alert("Length is "+n.length);
                item1=IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/PreviousEditionD");
                alert("Item1 "+ item1);
                for(var i=0;i<n.length-1;i++)
                {
                    alert(n[i]);
                }



            }
         function concatPath()
       {
           var item = IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/NextEditionVpathD").getValue();
           var path=NextPath+item;
           IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/NextEditionVpath").setValue(path);
           alert("Next Edition "+IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/NextEditionVpath").getValue());   
       }
       function setPrev()
       {
            var item = IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/PreviousEditionD");
            var item1=item.getOptions()[item.getValue()].value;
            IWDatacapture.getItem("/Config/PreviousEdition").setValue(item1);
            alert("previous Edition  " +item1);
       }
        </script>
}
```

This code working fine if i not use for loop, but after for loop, at the time of execution its giving error at mentioned in Title. Can you please tell how to fix it.

{org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 8): ';'}
Thanks

Comment: Not without the code after the for loop we can't. the for loop was you trying to figure out what was wrong, nothing to do with the real issue. Oh and what is in str?

Comment: Inside str i have =" /iwmnt/default/main/branch/EDITION/EDITION2-/iwmnt/default/main/branch/EDITION/EDITION1-/iwmnt/default/main/branch/EDITION/INITIAL-"

Comment: I have updated code, Now its complete code in js. This code is inside XML.

Comment: Problem Solved :) Added CDATA Tag.